# How to delete mu4e attachment on macOS

Tags: osx, mu4e, attachment

I want to delete a large attachment from a mu4e message. [This thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23812/remove-attachments-from-emails) is similar, except that the required `altermime` tool does not seem available on `macOS` (not on Homebrew and no results from an online search).

How can I delete an attachment from a `mu4e` message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to compile `altermime` yourself, you could install it from [macports](https://www.macports.org/) then follow @mankoff [recipe](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/23815/11477).

Answer (score 1):

My solution (at your link) involved manually installing `altermime` back when I used OS X. I don't think it was hard. Perhaps only `make` was required when I tried?

Comment: Actually it's even easier, it's on macports, which was what I used back the osx days. Anyway, probably will be on other installers. I don't think that compiling the source will be too hard.

Comment: Installing from source with the latest stable release altermime-0.3.10.tar.gz from https://pldaniels.com/altermime/ failed with `make`: `mime_alter.c:709:13: error: variable 'newblock' is used uninitialized whenever ...`. I was able to install it with Macports, getting the [Macports installer](https://www.macports.org/install.php) and running `sudo ports install altermime`. @Muihlinn Care to write an answer?